# Simple table running off page

Tags: tables

I'm trying to use a table to display some information but the text runs right off the page. Take a look:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}

\begin{enumerate} 

\item Rationale/Theoretical Reasoning (Hoe does your lesson target specific features of one or more of the five reform appraoches?)
\vspace{1cm}

\item Materials, Resources, Safety

 \begin{itemize}
 \item Battery
 \item Copper Wire 
 \item Screw/Bolt 
 \item Electrical Tape 
 \item Box Cutter 
 \item Wire Cutter 
 \end{itemize}    

\vspace{1cm}

\item NYS Learning Standards 

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
\hline
Sequence & Performance Indicators\\
\hline
III.6 & A circuit is a closed path in which a current* can exist.\\
\hline
III.8 & Circuit components may be connected in series* or in parallel.* Schematic diagrams are used to represent circuits and circuit elements\\
\hline
III.9 & Moving electric charges produce magnetic fields. The relative motion between a conductor and a magnetic field may produce a potential difference in the conductor\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}   
\end{enumerate}    

\end{flushleft} 

\end{document}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The `l,c,r` column specifier are for single-line cells. You have to choose paragraph column types that allow text wrapping. I suggest the `tabularx` environment, for which you can set the overall table width. Here is a code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx} 

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Rationale/Theoretical Reasoning (Hoe does your lesson target specific features of one or more of the five reform appraoches?)
\vspace{1cm}

\item Materials, Resources, Safety

 \begin{itemize}
 \item Battery
 \item Copper Wire
 \item Screw/Bolt
 \item Electrical Tape
 \item Box Cutter
 \item Wire Cutter
 \end{itemize}
\vspace{1cm}

\item NYS Learning Standards

\begin{center}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| c | X |}
\hline
Sequence & Performance Indicators\\
\hline
III.6 & A circuit is a closed path in which a current* can exist.\\
\hline
III.8 & Circuit components may be connected in series* or in parallel.* Schematic diagrams are used to represent circuits and circuit elements\\
\hline
III.9 & Moving electric charges produce magnetic fields. The relative motion between a conductor and a magnetic field may produce a potential difference in the conductor\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{enumerate}

\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image]